# Comparision of Textbooks for Topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I will take Introduction to Topology in next semester. The professor lists two reference books, Topology (by Sheldon Davis)/Topology (by Munkres). I know the textbook written by Munkres is a classic one. But it seems the professor prefers us using the textbook by Davis.

I have checked Amazon and there is no customer review about the textbook by Davis. Is there anyone who has read that book before? Could you make some comments on the textbook by Davis or help me compare these two textbooks?

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Unless you have some reason to dispute your professor's choice, which seems unlikely, i would go with that one.  Topology is an enormous field, and although the intro class is very likely to cover certain classic topics, the more specialized topics and the approach/viewpoint from which your professor wants to teach are going to be very important, so if s/he prefers one of those books over the other, it could easily have something to do with that, and you'll have an easier time following the course using his/her textbook of choice.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: To add to Callus's comment: while Munkres is definitely considered a classic, it is by no means a perfect reference for all situations. I think it is unsuited for a one-semester introduction to topology, though a careful selection from it is marvelous for a two-semester introductory course or for a strictly point-set topology course. In particular, its complete omission of homology is regrettable, because it would give the reader something he could actually compute (as opposed to the fundamental group).

Comment: Comment continued: I took topology without using Munkres (though I desperately wanted to), and my professor did a terrific job with the course - we didn't do point-set topology in the detail Munkres goes into, but we went through many interesting and applicable theorems (winding numbers, homology, etc.) that Munkres neglects; moreover, we were able to focus more on geometry and less on abstract point-set. Your professor may have his own ideas about where Munkres falls flat, and perhaps intends to make up for them by reading from Davis; try to give this other book a chance.

Comment: Thanks you kigen! Your comments are really helpful. I think my course may have similar course contents as yours. In my professor's lecture notes, order topology, metrization, urysohn lemma are skipped while homotopy is included. I think these contents match more with the materials of Davis. Currently I can't distinguish the concept of homotopy and homotopy . But as you suggested, I may buy the textbook by Davis.